# Nesting Projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, project

I see that MS has [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164696.aspx) on how to implement nesting projects when implementing new project types. While this looks do-able, I'd rather not write and maintain my own VS extension if I can avoid doing so. Is there any "generic" project type already implemented by some extension that will allow project nesting? The idea would be that the parent project does nothing but include its children and allow building, adding references, etc.

Comment: Have you considered using Shared Projects (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/315c13a7-2787-4f57-bdf7-adae6ed54450)?

Comment: Shared Projects seem to solve one kind of issue, but not quite the one I need solved. It solves the immediate issue for one project, but it doesn't seem to bring along all the dependencies of that shared project, if I understand it correctly. That means when I have App->Lib1->Lib2, I still have to add both Lib1 and Lib2 to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Managed Package Framework for Projects](https://mpfproj12.codeplex.com/) is for Visual Studio 2013 and includes "a project system that supports nesting" (see the NestedProject sample). I have not tried it myself, though I did look through it a while back (the VS 2010 version) and it has thorough documentation.

It may or may not be as extensive as what you are looking for. From the overview in the documentation:

> Creating a new project type in Visual Studio is complex task. Using MPF_Proj is a good starting point for creating custom project types in Visual Studio written in managed code but there are limitations that would have to be considered before using the framework.
>
> MPF_Proj is not a .NET library. It is rather a framework of source files (classes, utilities etc.) that can be included in a VSPackage project.

Comment: Thanks, looking through it. Looks like it will take me a while to figure out how to use...

Comment: Looks like this will work. It is not quite there, but it isn't too far away either. Thanks! I'll award the bounty when I'm allowed to do so.